# Memory lock to ensure shared data can be read from by many threads, but only written to by one?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-safety, shared-memory

I am trying to write a C# program where values in a list *A* are checked against a particular value *x* in a thread. I would like the threads to compare their *x* values to each of the ones in the list, and if it is not found, I would like them to add their value *x* to *A*. The thread will then get a new *x* from a list in it's private memory, and begin comparing it to the values in *A* again. The objective of this program is to make *A* a list of unique values, and contain all of the values of the lists in the threads.

I'm wondering if C# has some native read/write lock that will allow as many threads to read from a single list as possible, but once one starts to write, I would like all of the other threads to wait before attempting to read from the list again.

Also, is there a way I could ensure multiple threads won't attempt to write at the same time? I could see this being an issue if 2+ threads contained the same *x* value and tried to gain the write lock simultaneously - then added the same value to the list one after another.

Comment: If your question is just to make a unique list, you can use `HashSet`. Ofcourse, it has it's own limitations like no way to direct access elements.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks for the suggestion, I have considered this, but in my case these "values" aren't so easily compared. Essentially, they aren't *explicitly* equivalent, even though they are *considered* to be. I also don't know what the values "are", only if they are equal or not. So a hash function isn't possible to create..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering if C# has some native read/write lock that will allow as many threads to read from a single list as possible

Yes, use a [Reader Writer Lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6sth95%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That's what it's designed for.

There are two versions of ReaderWriterLock in .net  `ReaderWriterLock` and `ReaderWriterLockSlim` respectively. Latter one is preferred as it is efficient.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for! Do you have any suggestions as to how I can keep two threads from trying to write at once?

Comment: I guess I could use the TryEnterWriteLock(timeout) method with a timeout of 0, would this be sufficient?

Comment: @user3495690 I don't see the problem in two threads trying to write at the same time as long as they hold the lock (where one will wait for other).

Comment: It's just that I want the list to contain unique values, so if they both try to write the same value, the list will contain two instances of the same value, is all.

Comment: @user3495690 Yes exactly as you figured out you could use that method to see some other thread is holding the lock or not

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to be sure. Thanks a bunch for your help!